# RPC Node Providers errors while using solana on serverless functions

Tags: web3.js, rpc

Fetching a .sol DID requires me to use a RPC endpoint to setup the Connection object using @solana/web3.js. And @bonfida/spl-name-service SDK helps me in reverse lookup of a sol domain from the address using the Connection object.

I am sending the wallet address from the frontend to my server (specifically TRPC server hosted with nextjs app). And specifically for this function the error returns something like this.

error message:

```
Access to fetch at '<RPC_ENDPOINT>' from origin '<Site_Link>' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```